# Diamond White Patch, Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have built a diamond using MAX software and imported its .js file in my code.

```
//diamond script
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
logo = function(object){
    diamond = new THREE.Mesh(object, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff}));
    scene.add(diamond);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

loader.load('./assets/js/diamondScript.js',logo);
```

The problem is when i run the code, white patch (shown in image below) appears. The image is built transparent in the software, but implementing in code it show's white patch.

[Diamond with white patch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8jwi.png)

Now, when i move my mouse down then white patch disappears as the camera changes. (shown in image below)

[white patch disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNfgW.png)

Can anyone please guide me through this? i need transparent diamond i.e no white space.

Comment: Looks to me like the problem is with your mesh you are exporting from MAX. It looks like each poly is it's own object. Are you exporting your diamond correctly? Did you make sure that your diamond is a single mesh in MAX? Did you collapse all modifiers in MAX? Are all the normals correct in MAX? Have all the overlapping verticies been welded in MAX?

Comment: Each polygon is not its own object, Should there be some external textures applied on it ? as i has only shader loaded on it. Is UV maps required ?

Comment: can you post the json-file somewhere? Also try rendering with a) `wireframe: true`, b) any material that handles lighting properly (like `MeshPhongMaterial`), c) `side: THREE.DoubleSide` or d) adding a `THREE.NormalsHelper` to your scene. Suspicion is that the normals/triangle-winding-order is not consistent.

Comment: I'm new to three.js please guide me. I used side: THREE.DoubleSide earlier but it didnt went useful also wireframe: true but the feel of diamond fades away.